# Are any questions about any linguistic aspects allowed?

Tags: discussion, scope

So over here, are any questions about any linguistic aspects allowed, such as the different pronounciations of Spanish, silent letters in French etc. (I was just asking about this site)

Answer (score 2):

Your question is too vague to result in an informative answer. What do you mean by "any linguistic aspects" or "the different pronunciations of Spanish"? Not everything that has to do with language is "linguistic". Linguistics asks scientific questions about language, therefore it has to be underlyingly a scientific question, meaning that it has to look scientific. For example questions about pronunciation might be about the theory of phonology or the theory of phonetics, for example "does any language have both x and χ as phonemes?" is at least implicitly a theory question (if the answer is no, why are there no such languages – an interesting theoretical puzzle). Questions about what is "common" in language would be theory questions of a sort, since many people think that theory is supposed to explain statistical distribution.

The question should have a discernible relation to some aspect of linguistic theory, it is not enough that a question "be about" language. Orthography is one aspect of language that is treated scientifically, but what possible scientific question could be asked about "silent letters" in French (answers: (1) what historically gave rise to silent letters n French; (2) are silent letters in French processes psycholinguistically as efficiently as non-silent letters?...)

Answer (score 0):

No. For your specific examples, https://spanish.stackexchange.com/ and https://french.stackexchange.com/ would be appropriate. If the language you're interested in is not covered by some language-specific site, try https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/. This SE is primarily is about the scientific study of language.